# Difference between Indigo and Europa versions of Eclipse for Java EE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-europa

I would like to know the difference between the Eclipse Europa and Indigo versions for Java EE. Could anyone please tell me?

Answer (score 3):

The Eclipse Indigo release contains [WTP 3.3](http://eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.3.0/release-notes.php). This is very 'new' release.

The Eclipse Europa release contains [WTP 2.0](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/2.0/index.php). Europa was released in 2007, so it is fairly old.

There have been [three Eclipse releases between Europa and Indigo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases). There is a [page that has links to all of the various WTP 'New and Noteworthy' pages](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/development/news/main.php).